# How can I split variable X into 2 variables depending on a character in X?

Tags: r

I have a variable that looks like this:

```
df$Code
22
34
24
12
44
```

How can I create a new variable in the data frame, such that a subject with a value of "4" in `df$Code` is grouped as "Patient", while everyone else is grouped as "Controls" in a new `df$Groups`?

```
df$Groups
Control
Patient
Patient
Control
Patient
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hi :) should "42" (for ex) be considered as "Patient" too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
        mutate(group = ifelse(str_detect(as.character(Code), "4"), "Patient", "Control"))
```

Output:

```
   Code group  
  <dbl> <chr>  
1    22 Control
2    34 Patient
3    24 Patient
4    12 Control
5    44 Patient
```

Note that it detects "4" no matter if it comes first (e.g. 42) or second (e.g. 24) as I assumed this is what you want. If only the last digit should match, then use:

```
df %>% 
        mutate(group = ifelse(str_ends(as.character(Code), "4"), "Patient", "Control"))
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the solution for me. Yes, the goal is to define a subject as a patient if he/she has a value of "4" in either the first or second characters.

Answer (score 4):

In case the last digit should be tested if it is a `4` `endsWith` or `grepl` could be used:

```
c("Control", "Patient")[1 + endsWith(as.character(df$Code), "4")]
#[1] "Control" "Patient" "Patient" "Control" "Patient"

c("Control", "Patient")[1 + grepl("4$", df$Code)]
#[1] "Control" "Patient" "Patient" "Control" "Patient"
```

or at any position:

```
c("Control", "Patient")[1 + grepl("4", df$Code)]
#[1] "Control" "Patient" "Patient" "Control" "Patient"
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(Code = c(22, 34, 24, 12, 44))
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively a function such as `recode()` is ideal for this - especially if you have more than two categories.

```r
library(tidyverse)

tibble(code = c(22, 34, 24, 12, 44)) %>% 
  mutate(
    group = recode(code %% 10, `2` = "patient", `4` = "control")
  )

#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>    code group  
#>   <dbl> <chr>  
#> 1    22 patient
#> 2    34 control
#> 3    24 control
#> 4    12 patient
#> 5    44 control
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

We could use `grepl` in combination with `ifelse`

```
library(dplyr)
df  %>% 
  mutate(Groups = ifelse(
    grepl("4", as.character(Code)), 'Patient', 'Control'))
```

Output:

```
 Code Groups 
  <dbl> <chr>  
1    22 Control
2    34 Patient
3    24 Patient
4    12 Control
5    44 Patient
```